# Why does $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!} \left| x^ky^l\right| =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (|x|+|y|)^n$, when $n=k+l$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why does $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}  \left| x^ky^l\right| =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (|x|+|y|)^n$, when $n=k+l$?

This was given as fact to see that $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}  \left| x^ky^l\right| $ converges when $|x|+|y|<1$, but I don't see how it can be rearranged in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}  \left| x^ky^l\right| $$
Let $ n = k + l$
$$=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{l\ge 0}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-l)! l!}|x^{n-l}y^l|$$
$$=\sum_{n\ge0}(|x| + |y|)^n$$

Answer (score 1):

It is just the binomial theorem,
$(a+b)^n
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}
$
applied to the right side
and rearranged.